# Parse XML file for build ID from TeamCity Rest API Request

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to retrieve all of the build ID's from my TeamCity Rest API call. **I want to store them in a list.**

Currently I have an xml file that is formatted as shown below:

```
/<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<builds count="3" href="/app/rest/buildTypes/id:<id>/builds?locator=startDate:20230401T000000-0400,untilDate:20230431T000000-0400">
    <build id="419618" buildTypeId="Azure_Dev_ExternalSummary" number="E-9020" >
        <finishOnAgentDate>20230422T021844-0400</finishOnAgentDate>
    </build>
    <build id="419017" buildTypeId="Azure_Dev_ExternalSummary" number="E-9002"> 
        <finishOnAgentDate>20230420T173730-0400</finishOnAgentDate>
    </build>
    <build id="418538" buildTypeId="Azure_Dev_ExternalSummary" number="E-8987">
        <finishOnAgentDate>20230419T160253-0400</finishOnAgentDate>
    </build>
</builds>
```

But I cannot figure out how to get the ElementTree library to parse this xml file correctly.
I was trying the below code, but keep getting various errors.

```html
def extract_build_id(xmlfile):
    tree = ET.parse(xmlfile)

    root = tree.getroot()

    ids = []
    print('')
    for item in root.findall(''):
        print(item)
```

Maybe ElementTree isn't the best option for what I am trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `BeautifulSoup` to parse the xml file if `xml.etree.ElementTree` is not working

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# your sample xml data
xml = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<builds count="3" href="/app/rest/buildTypes/id:<id>/builds?locator=startDate:20230401T000000-0400,untilDate:20230431T000000-0400">
    <build id="419618" buildTypeId="Azure_Dev_ExternalSummary" number="E-9020" >
        <finishOnAgentDate>20230422T021844-0400</finishOnAgentDate>
    </build>
    <build id="419017" buildTypeId="Azure_Dev_ExternalSummary" number="E-9002"> 
        <finishOnAgentDate>20230420T173730-0400</finishOnAgentDate>
    </build>
    <build id="418538" buildTypeId="Azure_Dev_ExternalSummary" number="E-8987">
        <finishOnAgentDate>20230419T160253-0400</finishOnAgentDate>
    </build>
</builds>"""

# create the soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, 'xml')
# list comprehension to get the ID from each build tag
id_list = [b['id'] for b in soup.findAll('build')]  # -> ['419618', '419017', '418538']
```

Comment: This is the error I am getting now. C:\Users\creech\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\bs4\builder\__init__.py:545: XMLParsedAsHTMLWarning: It looks like you're parsing an XML document using an HTML parser. If this really is an HTML document (maybe it's XHTML?), you can ignore or filter this warning. If it's XML, you should know that using an XML parser will be more reliable. To parse this document as XML, make sure you have the lxml package installed, and pass the keyword argument `features="xml"` into the BeautifulSoup constructor.
  warnings.warn( @It_is_Chris

Comment: It is just a warning and everything should still run as expected but go ahead and add `features="xml"` which should resolve the warning.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse with `xml.etree.ElementTree`:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.parse("BuildID.xml").getroot()

id_list = []
for elem in root.iter('build'):
    id_list.append(elem.get("id"))

print(id_list) # ['419618', '419017', '418538']
```

Answer (score 0):

Clean the href before you parse. (No need for external lib)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import xml.sax.saxutils
import re

xml_doc = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<builds count="3" href="/app/rest/buildTypes/id:<id>/builds?locator=startDate:20230401T000000-0400,untilDate:20230431T000000-0400">
    <build id="419618" buildTypeId="Azure_Dev_ExternalSummary" number="E-9020" >
        <finishOnAgentDate>20230422T021844-0400</finishOnAgentDate>
    </build>
    <build id="419017" buildTypeId="Azure_Dev_ExternalSummary" number="E-9002"> 
        <finishOnAgentDate>20230420T173730-0400</finishOnAgentDate>
    </build>
    <build id="418538" buildTypeId="Azure_Dev_ExternalSummary" number="E-8987">
        <finishOnAgentDate>20230419T160253-0400</finishOnAgentDate>
    </build>
</builds>'''
pattern = r'href="([^"]*)"'
modified_xml_content = re.sub(pattern, lambda match: 'href="' + xml.sax.saxutils.escape(match.group(1)) + '"', xml_doc)
root = ET.fromstring(modified_xml_content)
ids = [b.attrib['id'] for b in root.findall('.//build')]
print(ids)
```

output

```
['419618', '419017', '418538']
```